# Squish doesn't enter entire file path

Tags: python, squish

I have run into a problem in Squish where when the automated test opens the window to upload a file from my computer to my application, it cuts parts off the beginning of the file path.

For example:

This is the correct path Squish should enter with the function "nativeType": `/home/user/images/`

But Squish enters something like this:

`/ome/user/images/`

or

`/me/user/images/`

or

`/e/user/images/`

Sometimes the file path is entered correctly, but most of the time the examples above are entered.

This is what I am using:

Ubuntu Version: 18.04

Squish IDE 6.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it works to send the characters one by one, possibly with a short delay in between:

```
def nativeTypeOneByOne(to_type, snooze_in_between=0.1):
    for c in to_type:
        snooze(snooze_in_between)
        nativeType(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe squish is trying to enter the string before the element in your UI is ready, so the first part is sometimes missing. You could use  waitForObject() to start typing until the input field is ready.

```
waitForObject(inputFieldRealName)
nativeType(stringToInput)
```

Alternatively, you could use snooze(timeInSecs) if the problem is squish taking too much time to focus on the input field. Use snooze() carefully and only when there is no other choice. If you overuse it, you´ll end with a sluggish suite.